# Drawing a function that isn't $x^3$ with a critical number that is not a local extremum.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have a problem that I'm not sure how to do at all. It says,

> Sketch the graph of a function that is continuous on $[1, 5]$ and has an absolute maximum at $2$, an absolute minimum at $5$, and a critical number at $4$, but no local maximum or minimum there.

I know that $f=x^3$ has a critical number that isn't an extremum, but it doesn't have any absolute extrema either.

I am not sure how to draw a critical point that isn't a local minimum or maximum, and yet still has absolute extrema.

*How can I draw a function with absolute extrema, and that has a critical point that isn't a local extremum?*

Comment: You just have to draw the function.  You can draw a function that locally looks like a shifted version of $x^3$ in places, and then bends up/down however you want.  No need to figure out a mathematical expression that goes with the function.

Comment: @Michael But how do I draw a critical point without drawing a local min or max?

Comment: Just practice by drawing $x^3$ first.

Comment: @Michael That has no absolute extrema.

Comment: Which is why I said that it could bend up/down however you want after the location where it is supposed to have a critical point but no local minimum or maximum at that point.  That is a local requirement only, it only needs to take place around the point $x=4$.

Comment: @Michael How can it bend without being a local extrema? That is my question.

Comment: Have you ever drawn a sine curve? $\sin(x)$ or $\cos(x)$?

Comment: @Michael A sine graph has local extrema and absolute extrema in the same place.

Comment: The sine curve goes up and down.  Somehow you can envision a function $x^3$ locally about $0$ but you cannot imagine it ever bending back down after $x=0$, say, starting to bend down at $x=1$.

Comment: Do you understand that whether a point is a local minimum, a local maximum, or a critical point depends only on how the function behaves in a *neighbourhood* of that point, not on the entire rest of the domain? So, can you draw a graph that, in a range say $[3.5, 4.5]$, looks like the graph of $x^3$ on $[-0.5,0.5]$, and outside that range does something else?

Comment: "I am not sure how to draw a critical point that isn't a local minimum or maximum"  In my classes we called them saddle points.  $f$ "flattens out" at $x$ but rather rather than reversing and going "back" down or "back" up, is revs up/down again.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

[image]
If I have understood your question right then your function should look like this. It should have a Maxima at 2 .minima at 5. It should change its curvature from convex to concave at 4. Notice that these are local Maxima/minima so function can assume values larger/smaller than those at local Maxima/minima

Comment: It seems Luminous Nutria has abandoned the (good) hint about $x^3$ as an aid to satisfying the criteria.  That function was useful not because it changes convexity curvature (although it does that too).

Comment: A critical point, where the derivative is $0$ or the function is not differentiable, is different from a point of inflection, where the curve changes concavity. Your graph has $4$ as a point of inflection, not as a critical point.

Comment: -1 as "critical point" is a fundamental requirement which this simply botches.

Comment: Maxima and minima are plural.  The singular forms are maximum and minimum.

Answer (score 1):

Sketch means to draw a picture describing it.  Not to actually find the expression of one.

Assuming continuity and differentiability then:

An absolute maximum at $2$ means: as $1 < 2 < 5$ it must also be a local maximum so the function "plateaus" at two and the $f'(x)=0$ so it "flattens out" at $x = 2$.

A critical point that is neither a local maximum or minimum means (if it is differentiable) means it "flattens" out at $x=4$ but neither "plateaus" or "valleys".  So it "passes through".

And as 5 is an extreme point of the interval $[1,5]$, an absolute minimum just means the lowest point on the interval. It need not be a critical point.

If you forgive the crappy graphics:

[image]

Comment: Preferably substantiate using an example, like $(4-x)^3$

Comment: "Preferably substantiate using an example, like $(4−x)^3$" Why?  $(4-x)^3$ doesn't have a local max at $x =2$.  And point is to know the concepts.  Not to do the math.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean absolute extrema on the interval $[1, 5]$, then
$$
f(x) = \left(x-2\right)^{3} \cos\left(x-2\right)
$$
will do it: you can graph it using [the Desmos online graphing calculator](https://www.desmos.com/calculator).  You will see, and can verify using calculus, that this function:

- has a critical, non-extremal point at $x=2$, and
- a maximum global on $[1, 5]$ (and interior to $[1, 5]$) somewhere near $x = 3.2$.

But if you meant global extrema on the entire real line, then the above function has none.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you could solve this by giving a cubic with three roots, the middle root being 4 (i.e. a critical point which isn't a min or max), then have the smallest root less than 2, e.g. 0, and the largest root greater than 5, e.g. 6. There will be some algebra to do. You need to decide which roots to give your cubic to ensure that the max and min will be at 2 and 5 respectively.

$$y = (x-a)(x-4)(x-b), a<2, b>5$$
$$dy / dx = a(4+b-2x)-2b(-2+x)+x(-8+3x)$$

For this to be equal $0 $ at $2 $ and $5$, we require:
$ab-4=0 (ab=4)$ , and
$a(b-6)-6b+35=0 $

i.e. $ab-6a-6b+35=0$

this gives us
$4-6a-6b+35=0$

using $a=4/b$
$4-24/b-6b+35=0$
$4b-24-6b^2+35b=0$

solving gives us $b = 13/4 + \sqrt{105}/4$,
$a = 4/(13/4 + \sqrt{105}/4)$

Comment: Please do not vandalize your answer.  If you are unhappy with your answer, you should be able to simply delete it.

Comment: It is incorrect, we will delete it.

Comment: You're welcome to delete it, but you are not welcome to vandalize it and leave it non-deleted.

Comment: That is really great how do I delete it, also who are you

Comment: Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221"). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the answer, on the left in line with the "share" and "edit". You may need to use a browser, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the graph of $f(x)=x^3,x=0$ is a critical point since $f'(0)=0$. But $0$ is not a point of extremum. What's more, $f''(0)=0$ and the curve changes concavity at $x=0$.

You can perform a simple translation of this curve to get one possible solution to your question. Since we require $4$ to be a critical point without having an extremum there, we may shift the origin to $4$. We also require absolute maximum at $2$ and absolute minimum at $5$. Seeing the increasing nature of $x^3$, we flip it by taking its reflection about the $y$ axis, and for $x\le2$ and $x\ge5$, redefine $f(x)$ to be equal to, say, $f(2)=8$.

[image]
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}8,&x<2\vee x>5\\(4-x)^3,&x\in[2,5]\end{cases}$$